# .bashrc or .bash_profile for ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, bash, bashrc

Which profile, **.bashrc** or **.bash_profile**, is the appropriate spot for ssh-agent?  I'm looking for an answer that explains the different between an interactive shell and a login shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends somewhat on how you personally use shells.

An interactive shell is anything that has a terminal connected to its input and output. Login shells are spawned by /bin/login. Login shells source your .bash_profile. Most terminal emulators such as xterm start an interactive shell that is not a login shell. Interactive, non-login shells source your .bashrc.

What I typically do is have my .bash_profile source my .bashrc (after checking if it has already been sourced), and then I put my ssh-agent setup in my .bashrc.

Comment: What's the check in .bash_profile to see if .bashrc has been sourced already?

Comment: Nothing special. I generally just check to see if a variable I set in .bashrc is set.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.bash_profile` because `.bashrc` is sourced for every interactive shell and you only need one agent per login session.

Answer (score 0):

ssh-agent is a wrapper program.
You would typically want to do a "`exec ssh-agent bash`" at the start.